# PHP loop db query until value changes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically i have rate limit from my API provider for 50 simultaneous jobs. as an example lets say i have to run 500 jobs:

`$jobs = $this->db->get('jobs')->result_array();` (loads all 500 jobs)

Bellow code loops api query for all 500 jobs.

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
//API call
}
```

each job has status parameter $job['status'], i want to do the following:

to avoid abuse of rate limit, i want to count rows with busy status
`$busy = $this->db->get_where('jobs', ['status' => 'busy']->num_rows();`

and keep on checking (looping) until $busy < 50

Final results

```
foreach($jobs as $job)
{
//API call
//Count busy jobs
//If busy >= 50 wait(50) and check again - (I need help with this part, no idea how to do it)
//If busy < 50 continue foreach loop
}
```

Hope all details are in place.

p.s.
I am using:

CodeIgniter3, PHP7.4

Edit:

To avoid confusion as mentioned in final result (//If busy >= 50 wait(50) and check again - (I need help with this part, no idea how to do it)
)

I am looking for a way to loop $busy SQL query until num_row() will be less than 50.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You forgot to mention what your actual issue is. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Issue is mentioned in final result: //If busy >= 50 wait(50) and check again - (I need help with this part, no idea how to do it)

Comment: How are you making this call to the API, and how do you know when a job is complete in order to start the next one?

Comment: When job is finished i receive webbook with status update to my endpoint, this is why i want to loop $busy(code is above) mysql query to check for status updates.

Comment: What do you hope `wait(50)` will do?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution

```
$busy = $this->db->get_where('jobs', ['status' => 'busy']->num_rows();
while($busy >= 50 ) {
$busy = $this->db->get_where('jobs', ['status' => 'busy']->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: A better solution would be to get your webhook to look for any outstanding jobs and if it finds some, issue the next call to the API. This avoids the need to loop while the tasks complete.

Comment: Thanks for an advice, issue is that once API is called and job is finished on my end it can still be pending with API Provider. that is why i am following up on statuses received by provider.